# Calculate the line integral of the vector field along the line between the given points.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, line-integrals

Can someone give me some assistance on this problem? We are only solving line integrals geometrically.

$F = -5\vec{i} + 7\vec{j}$ from $(0,5)$ to $(3,16)$

At the moment, I am stuck with finding the limits of integration and $d\vec{r}$. Thanks

Comment: Do you know the "Fundamental Theorem for Line Integrals"? If so, note that $\vec{F} = \nabla f$ for $f(x,y) = -5x + 7y$. Then you can get the answer without actually computing an integral.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\vec{F}(x,y)=\langle -5,7\rangle = \nabla f=\langle f_x, f_y \rangle$, where $f(x,y)=-5x+7y$, we use the Fundamental Theorem for line integrals to obtain: 
$$
\begin{align*}
\int_C \vec{F} \cdot d\vec{r} &= \int_C \nabla f \cdot d\vec{r} \\
&= f(3,16)-f(0,5) \\
&= -5(3)+ 7(16)-(-5(0)+7(5)) \\ 
&= 62. \\  
\end{align*}
$$

Answer (score 2):

We have

$$\begin{align}
\int_C\vec F\cdot d\vec r&=\int_{(0,5)}^{(3,16)}(-5\vec i+7\vec j)\cdot (\vec i\,dx+\vec j\,dy)\\\\
&=-\int_0^3 5\,dx+\int_5^{16}7\,dy\\\\
&=62
\end{align}$$